# Deep association relating to top-level model?

Tags: cakephp

I have the following models:

- `Kin`, which you can think of as an animal--a pet.
- `Species` `hasAndBelongsToMany` `Kin`
- `GrowthStage` `hasAndBelongsToMany` `Species`
- `Kin` `hasAndBelongsToMany` `GrowthStage`
- and `KinGrowthStage`, which defines the relationship between a kin and its growth stages (it contains its related images and such for the kin at that growth stage).

So in my controller I'm trying to get the following array to come out the other end. In this scenario the Species => GrowthStage => KinGrowthStages are related to the Kin id:

```
Array
(
    [Kin] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Hobbes
        [generation] => 1
        [current_growth_stage_id] => 4
        [species_id] => 1
    )
    [Species] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Tiger
        [GrowthStage] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [name] => cub
                [order] => 1
                [KinGrowthStage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [growth_stage_id] => 1
                        [kin_id] => 4
                        [image] => /img/hobbes/cub.png
                    )
                )
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => juvenile
                [order] => 2
                [KinGrowthStage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [growth_stage_id] => 1
                        [kin_id] => 4
                        [image] => /img/hobbes/juvenile.png
                    )
                )
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
                [name] => adult
                [order] => 3
                [KinGrowthStage] => Array
                (
                    // Nothing here because Hobbes hasn't reached this growth stage yet
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

What I'm getting is this. The Species => GrowthStage => KinGrowthStages is joining on the GrowthStage id rather than the Kin id:

```
Array
(
    [Kin] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Hobbes
        [generation] => 1
        [current_growth_stage_id] => 4
        [species_id] => 1
    )
    [Species] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Tiger
        [GrowthStage] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [name] => cub
                [order] => 1
                [KinGrowthStage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [growth_stage_id] => 1
                        [kin_id] => 1
                        [image] => /img/tony/cub.png
                    )
                )
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => juvenile
                [order] => 2
                [KinGrowthStage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [growth_stage_id] => 2
                        [kin_id] => 1
                        [image] => /img/tony/juvenile.png
                    )
                )
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
                [name] => adult
                [order] => 3
                [KinGrowthStage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [growth_stage_id] => 3
                        [kin_id] => 1
                        [image] => /img/tony/adult.png
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I understand *why* this happening, I just want to know if there's any way to modify the relationship 'on the fly' and join it on the kin id. I've tried adding the following conditions array to my contain array:

```
$this->Kin->contain(
    array(
        'Species' => array(
            'GrowthStage' => array(
                'KinGrowthStage' => array(
                    'conditions' => array('Kin.id = KinGrowthStage.kin_id'),
                ),
                'order' => 'GrowthStage.order ASC'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

But I get an error about 'unknown table `Kin`'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Linkable Behavior https://github.com/Terr/linkable

```
$this->Kin->find('all', array(
    'link'  => array(
        'Species'  => array(
            'GrowthStage' => array(
                'KinGrowthStage' => array(
                    'conditions'    => 'Kin.id = KinGrowthStage.kin_id', 
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'order' => 'GrowthStage.order ASC'
));
```